# How is message consumed from Kafka in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I understand a batch of data will be consumed every time to reduce the network calls but does the rate of consuming  depend on the source operator only or the acknowledgement of Sink also matters? How is burst handled in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The source and sink are loosely coupled. If the sink can't keep up, then this will cause backpressure that will cascade up through the job graph, preventing the source from being able to write data downstream faster than it is being consumed, which will slow down the rate at which it reads (thereby matching the sink).

See [How Apache Flink handles backpressure](https://www.ververica.com/blog/how-flink-handles-backpressure)
 for more info.